# Android: How can I create Swipeable Stack view?

Tags: android, listview, stackview

I want to create swipeable stack view in my app. I attach the view below.
In that stack view, can I delete a particular item by swiping on item position?

[image]

Please provide me any reference example or tutorial.

Comment: please try out something and come up with suggestions, rather than asking for whole code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done with two ways:

[image]

1. [This one](http://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents)
2. [This one](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @yuchi_1k91, Glad to help you. :)

Comment: So. I found a problem. This project only support minSdkversion 22 to above :(

Comment: @yuchi_1k91, Yes I mentioned it as Note:

Comment: @yuchi_1k91, can you please try this one? https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents

Comment: @Hirent Patel  So thanks. I tried it. But it raise out Of Memory when load more items.

Comment: Warning:Dependency com.github.ZieIony:MaterialRecents:d2aec46f48 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users~.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.ZieIony\MaterialRecents\d2aec46f48\494f96d345471f38b6f3f4c1c42347a2b42f8303\MaterialRecents-d2aec46f48.apk

Can anyone tell me why i'm getting this?